# How to find out when PDF is loaded via embed tag

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, httphandler

I'm trying to display a PDF using an embed tag. The PDF is loaded from an HTTPHandler in .NET.

The displaying of the PDF works fine, but I want to know when the file is finished loading and displaying so I can run a JavaScript function.

I've tried binding in an event handler for onloadeddata, onload, onloadstart, onended and onplay, but none of them ever get hit.

Is what I want to do possible? If so, what event can I catch?

```
<embed src=@virtualPath  id="pdfiFrame" type="application/pdf" alt="pdf"  style="width: 100%; height: 99.4%;" frameborder="0" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html" onloadeddata='tryThis;' onload="tryThis;" onloadstart="tryThis;", onended="tryThis;" onplay="tryThis;"/>

function tryThis(arg) {
    alert("here = " + arg);
}
```

The path is defined in a variable in the MVC Razor view.

Doing anything from the handler itself is not an option as I am caching the results as well, so the handler won't be hit a second time for the same file.

Answer (score 0):

The entire PDF file may never load completely... especially if the PDF viewer is Adobe Reader but would also be true with any PDF viewer capable of leveraging "fast web view". PDF files are random access and a conforming viewer will only request the bytes from the server that are required to display the page requested. That's why you can open a PDF in a browser and, for example, immediately jump to page 500 of a 1000 page document without waiting for the whole thing to download. Web optimized PDF was designed specifically to *not* do what you are wanting it to do.

That said, you could try not setting the src property of the embed element in your HTML and use AJAX (or something) to fetch the PDF as a blob and then set the src property once the "done" event fired. Then you'd know you had the entire file *before* it even started to display.

Comment: You raise an interesting point about not necessarily loading the whole thing. What I really want to do is put up a modal progress indicator on the page until the document is ready for viewing. This doesn't have to mean the whole thing is there, just that the first page is visible. Any thoughts on how to do this part?

Comment: The Adobe Reader will sort of do this but it's pretty much guessing unless it's web-optimized and the likelihood of that being the default PDF viewer is pretty low these days. The problem you're going to have is that the typical PDF viewer doesn't know what bytes from the file are required for any given page. The objects are random access and a page object may refer to any number of other objects that may be shared or be unique to that page. The viewer only finds out that an object references another set of objects when it reads it.

Comment: old thread but hey if someone is looking for this, as a workaround I just use css to put the embed element over my loading icon, this way the loading icon will be visible untill the pdf is loaded and is over the actual loading icon.